# Collections.sort vs Arrays.sort - in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist

I was doing this sort first:

```
List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();

Comparator<items> ignoreLeadingThe = new Comparator<items>() {
    public int compare(String a, String b) {
        a = a.replaceAll("(?i(^the\\s+", "");
        b = b.replaceAll("(?i(^the\\s+", "");
        return a.compareToIgnoreCase(b);
    }
};

Collections.sort(items, ignoreLeadingThe);
```

now I am doing this:

```
ItemObject[] io = new ItemObject[items.size()];

Comparator<ItemObject> ignoreLeadingThe = new Comparator<ItemObject>() {
    public int compare(ItemObject a, ItemObject b) {
        a.name = a.name.replaceAll("(?i(^the\\s+", "");
        b.name = b.name.replaceAll("(?i(^the\\s+", "");
        return a.name.compareToIgnoreCase(b.name);
    }
};

Arrays.sort(io, ignoreLeadingThe);
```

When I was sorting the `ArrayList` up top, it acted as normal; it ignored the "The " and sorted list accordingly; but it wasn't actually effecting the output of the list.

However, the bottom code when I am sorting a regular `Array` (filled with Objects and not Strings), actually remove "The ".  For example,  "The Joker", would become "Joker".

Does anyone see what is going wrong here?

Comment: You're overwriting `a.name` and `b.name`. Declare separate local variables for the transformed names and use those in your `compareToIgnoreCase`.

Comment: You want to write: `String newA = a.name.replaceAll("(?i(^the\\s+", "");` instead.

Comment: In the method compare(String, String) of the comparator, you expressly delete "the" from every string, changing the string. You could use temporary strings in that method and operate on the temporary strings, that should fix it.

Comment: @G.Bach `String` is immutable, the problem is that he is modifying the `name`s of the `ItemObject`s.

Comment: @veer: I was being imprecise, I should have written that the assignment he does to a.name and b.name assigns strings that had "the" deleted from the original strings. You are right of course that the original String objects aren't changed since they're immutable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I stated in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12205950/collections-sort-vs-arrays-sort-in-java#comment16348476_12205950),

> You're overwriting `a.name` and `b.name`. Declare separate local variables for the transformed names and use those in your `compareToIgnoreCase`.

... or just use one large expression. So, try something like this...

```
final Comparator<ItemObject> ignoreLeadingThe = new Comparator<ItemObject>() {

  final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?i(^the\\s+");

  public int compare(final ItemObject a, final ItemObject b) {
    return pattern.matcher(a.name).replaceAll("")
        .compareToIgnoreCase(pattern.matcher(b.name).replaceAll(""));
  }
};
```